# bound OSM points to lines

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap

I try to use OSM power lines poles vector data to render 3d power line poles into 3D gis program osgearth.

So in OSM data there are power line poles as points and power lines as lines. So I use point coordinates to place poles, but I don't know orientation of pole. Also I have lines, but theese lines are not bounded to poles. Another way is use OSM lines data to populate poles across line, but there is disadvantage that pole can be placed in river or house.

So I think of using for example QGIS to bound line data to point data, or calculate closest point to specific point and write it to point attributes  so if I have two points I can calculate azimuth of pole. How can I use QGIS to achive this?